# Copying unsigned char array to uint32_t, and vice versa

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm trying to iteratively copy an unsigned char array to a uint_32t variable (in 4 byte blocks), perform some operation on the uint_32t variable, and copy it back to the unsigned char array.

Here's my code:

```
unsigned char byteArray[len]
for (int i=0; i<len; i+=4) {
  uint32_t tmpInt = 0;
  memcpy(&tmpInt, byteArray+(i*4), sizeof(uint32_t));
  // do some operation on tmpInt here
  memcpy((void*)(byteArray+(i*4)), &tmpInt, sizeof(uint32_t));
}
```

It doesn't work though. What's wrong, and how can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Can't reproduce an error. I set `byteArray[len] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`, then in the middle I do `tmpInt++` and in the end if I print the chars and I get  `2 2 3 4`.

Comment: How is the data stored in the 8 bit array, e.g. how is the value 2000 stored?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? (And why 4 and sizeof(uint32_t) in the same line?)

Comment: *It doesn't work though.*  **What** "doesn't work"?  Does your computer explode?  Does it clog your toilet?  "Doesn't work" isn't a useful description.

Comment: `i+=4` and `i*4` don't play well together.

Comment: The cast to `void*` is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out you are doing too much by incrementing `i` as well as  multiplying it by the size of your target.

On top of this

- the code shown might run into a buffer overflow issue reading beyond the source array.
- the `sizeof` operator evaluates to `size_t` not `int`.
- the code repeats defining the size of the target independently several times.

Fixing all, the result might look like this:

```
  unsigned char byte_array[len];

  typedef uint32_t target_type;
  const size_t s = sizeof (target_type);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < (len/s)*s; i += s) {
    target_type target;
    memcpy(&target, byte_array + i, s);

    // do some operation on target here

    memcpy(byte_array + i, &target, s);
  }
```

To avoid the `typedef` just define the target outside of the `for`-loop:

```
  unsigned char byte_array[len];

  {
    uint32_t target;
    const size_t s = sizeof target;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (len/s)*s; i += s) {
      memcpy(&target, byte_array + i, s);

      // do some operation on target here

      memcpy(byte_array + i, &target, s);
    }
  }
```

An equivalent to

```
byte_array + i
```

would be

```
&byte_array[i]
```

which might be more intuitively to read.

To avoid the "strange" `(len/s)*s` one could step away from using an index at all, but use a pointer instead:

```
for (unsigned char p = byte_array; p < byte_array + len; p += s) {
      memcpy(&target, p, s);

      // do some operation on target here

      memcpy(p, &target, s);
    }
```

In my opinion this is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks, after debugging it for a while more, I came up with a solution that more or less looks like this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are adding 4 to `i` with each iteration **and** multiplying by 4. You should be using `byteArray + i`.

Also, as @WeatherVane pointed out below, your loop would be more consistent with a sizeof():

`for (int i = 0; i < len; i += sizeof(uint32_t))`.

Comment: ...and `i+=4` should be `i += sizeof(uint32_t)` to be consistent.